# DAX - Multiple Filters with Multiple Tables and Columns

Tags: filtering, powerbi, dax

I've been struggling a bit with this and hopefully you can help me.

So I have a table with employee **Login** sessions with the following relevant columns: ***[Employee ID], [LoginTime], [LogoutTime], [Status]***

And another table with **Incident** IDs and its respective ***[Acknowledgement DateTime]*** and which ***[Employee ID]*** is handling it.

Now I'm looking to verify which **Login[Status]** the employee was in when he accepted the Incident.

So, I was thinking about something along these lines:

```
Calculate(Login[Status];
    Filter(Login;Login[Employee ID]=Incident[Employee ID];
    Filter(Login;
       and(Login[LoginTime<=Incident[AckDateTime];Login[LogoutTime>=Incident[AckDateTime])
```

So far I don't believe I'm getting the desired results, do you have any tips on how I should go about this?

Thanks in advance,
Cheers!

**Edit:** Thanks for the reply and apologies, it was my first question here.

The **Login** table should look like this:

`Employee ID     LoginTime           LogoutTime           Status Colossus        26/09/2018 13:05    26/09/2018 13:25     Available Nightcrawler    26/09/2018 11:30    26/09/2018 12:10     Research`

And the **Incident** one, like this:

`Incident ID     Employee ID     AckDateTime 12456324        Colossus        26/09/2018 13:24 45754121        Cyclops         26/09/2018 12:00 78452135        Nightcrawler    26/09/2018 11:15`

I've tried with other similar formulas which seem to make sense (to me at least) but PowerBI just breaks down with lack of sufficient memory issues.
The same happened with your suggested formula.

I'm working with a 200k+ row table with several columns so I'm looking to lighten this formula up, would this be possible with filters?

I mean, do they apply sequentially (narrowing down with each step) or does calculate apply all filters at once?

Comment: Can you give some sample input data along with desired output? Questions with a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) are much more likely to get a good answer.

Answer (score 0):

Please try to always provide a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) as this will help others help you!

If you add a ***New Calculated Column*** to your **Incident** Table you should be able to determine your Employee Status with something like this:

```
Employee Status =
    CALCULATE (
        MAX ( 'Login'[Status] ),
        FILTER (
            'Login',
            AND('Incident'[AckDateTime] > 'Login'[LoginTime],
                'Incident'[AckDateTime] <= 'Login'[LogoutTime]
            )
        )
    )
```